# Does volatile propagate to instance members?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

Suppose there is some simple container declared and instantiated like this

```
class Test {
    private volatile List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

, and reads and writes to it are guarded by locks; `synchronized` keyword not used. Although `Test.list` is declared volatile, none of its member fields like `ArrayList.elementData` also bear this modifier. Now, in multithreaded application, will it behave like volatile container? In other words, will changes submitted to `ArrayList.elementData` by some thread be visible immediately by all other threads?

Comment: Adding to the answers below, depending on the use case you may also want to consider [`AtomicReferenceArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceArray.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general answer is no: `volatile` only establishes a happens-before relationship between reads and writes to the reference variable. If two threads concurrently access an *inner field* of the object referenced in the variable, there still needs to be a synchronization mechanism.

In your case, the best approach seems to use a synchronized list, or some wrapper from the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no. As a consequence, array elements are always non-volatile (even if the array itself is declared volatile). You need to use special concurrent-friendly implementation of the `List`. Usually [`java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) fits the needs. If you assign the `list` variable only once, then volatile keyword does not change anything (in this case better to use `final`).

Comment: _even if the array itself is declared `volatile`_.  That's misleading because you're conflating an array _variable_ with an array _object_.  When somebody says, "an array" they usually are talking about the object; but an object can not be `volatile`.  Only a _variable_ can be `volatile`.  We can get away with that kind of talk when we're speaking with experienced developers, but the OP in this case clearly has only a weak understanding of the difference between objects and variables.